# SQLite multiple query selection OR

Tags: android, sqlite

Hey there are plenty of answers regarding multiple selection queries and I've read through all that i could find. My query seems correct to me but i can only get it working with one selection. Hopefully another pair of eyes can notice what i'm missing.

```
Cursor getSearch(String itemName) {
    String searchSelect = "( "+MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " LIKE ? OR"+
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST + " LIKE ? OR"+
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM + " LIKE ? )";
    String[]  selectArgs = { "%" + itemName + "%"};
    Cursor searchCursor = getContentResolver().query(
            queryUri,
            projection,
            searchSelect,
            selectArgs,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC"
    );
    return searchCursor;
}
```

Comment: you missed a few spaces : `OR"`

Comment: also, if you have 3 `?`,  you need 3 args in `selectArgs` (even if they are the same)

Comment: @njzk2 Thanks you, i knew it was something obvious. *x.x*
Okay thanks for the heads up i'll make that change. Is this just best practice? because it works just fine as is.

Comment: what would the modified selection args look like? (what should i put between the ...% %... )

Comment: probably something like `{ "%" + itemName + "%", "%" + itemName + "%", "%" + itemName + "%" }`

Comment: Your suggestion works as well. I wonder what the difference is?

Answer (score 0):

missing a space after OR

```
Cursor getSearch(String itemName) {
    String searchSelect = "( "+MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " LIKE ? OR "+
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST + " LIKE ? OR "+
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM + " LIKE ? )";
    String[]  selectArgs = { "%" + itemName + "%","%" + itemName + "%","%" + itemName + "%"};
    Cursor searchCursor = getContentResolver().query(
            queryUri,
            projection,
            searchSelect,
            selectArgs,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC"
    );
    return searchCursor;
}
```

Comment: I think you need to have 1 arg for each `?`, don't you?

Comment: i don't know if that is best practice but this is working as intended. If someone know that to be the right way to do it edit my answer or let me know and i will.

Comment: I am quite surprised that you would say that it works with only 1 arg. From what I recall, you are supposed to bind each `?` to one arg.

Comment: @njzk2 Missing parameters are just NULL.